# Adding 'Show More' functionality to a ASP Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarepeater, asprepeater

To put it as simple as I can. I have a website and the homepage is populated with an `ASP Repeater control`. This shows details of people you follows activities on the site within the last 30 days.

My problem being I dont want my homepage to be too long on loading if you follow lots of people and they have been participating in lots of recent activities, meaning the `repeater` will be extremely long and hence my page being stretched.

What I want is for the `repeater` to show say 15 items/rows then below this is a 'Show more' link which will show either show the rest or each time you click shows another 15 (either/or I will be happy with!)

Here is my `repeater` code...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptNewsFeed" runat="server" 
onitemdatabound="RptNewsFeed_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="NewsFeedItem">
        <div class="ProfileImageContainer">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HlkProfileImageLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <asp:Image ID="ImgProfileImage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
        <div class="ProfileLinkContainer">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HlkProfileLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="ActionDoneBy"></asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:Label ID="LblAction" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="Action"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HlkActionObjectLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="ActionDone"></asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
        <div class="TimeContainer">
            <asp:Label ID="LblActionTime" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: So what's the problem? Just keen an eye on your data binding mechanism, and control the number of items you feed to repeater on each postback.

Comment: How would i do that @Andrei?

Comment: I am sorry, but that's a too broad question. Have you tried to do this? If not, what exactly prevents you from trying? What part of that you do not understand?